# Error bars continuing (possibly) infinitely on plot despite data not doing so in r?

Tags: r, plot

I've been trying to plot a relatively big dataset in R and I'm having this issue where a couple of the error bars are ridiculously long in the positive direction despite the dataset not having anything like that in it. If anyone knows what could be causing this issue I would really appreciate the help!

Here's the code,

```
brangram<-read.table("BrainGrams.txt", header=TRUE)
BGspecies.nam<-brangram$Species
par(mar=c(5,9,4,2))
ddd<-barplot(brangram$Average, horiz=T, xlim=c(-2,5), col="white",border="white",las=1)
mtext("Log Brain",side=1,line=3)
mtext("Species",side=2,line=9)
arrows(brangram$LowestValue,ddd,brangram$HighestValue,ddd,code=3,angle=90,length=0.1)
points(brangram$Average,ddd,cex=0.5,pch=21,bg="black")
lines(c(-2,-2),c(0,10000),lty=2,lwd=2)
```

And here is the plot [image: plot],

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough data for others to reproduce your problem. Use `dput` to output the data in an easily read format